# onStartCommand not called with startService

Tags: java, android

I want to start a service from my activity class. The problem is, that `onStartCommand` never gets called. I placed breakpoint there and it is never hit. My example is really simple and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(TestService.class.getName());
        serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
        serviceIntent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

If I remove `serviceIntent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());` I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=package.TestService (has extras) }
```

That's why I added it to get rid of this error. But it still isn't working.

**TestService.java:**

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    public TestService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: You've not constructed the `Intent` correctly. Change it to `new Intent(this, TestService.class)`, and you can remove the `setPackage()` call.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

> Add in Activity class

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. Also can you please up-vote as well so this can be useful for other peoples also.